# Transactions in AWS Document DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-documentdb

How well is documentDB compared to dynamo DB, considering transactions capability ?

Following is an example of transaction operation done using dynamoDB.

```
const transactionResponse = await docClient.transactWrite({
            TransactItems: [
                {
                    Put: {
                        TableName: Table1,
                        Item: {
                            id,
                            userId,
                            anotherID,
                            createdAt: (new Date()).toISOString()
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    Update: {
                        TableName: Table2,
                        Key: {anotherID},
                        UpdateExpression: `set available = available - :val, count = count + :val, lastUpdatedDate = :updatedAt`,
                        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                            ":val": 1,
                            ":updatedAt": (new Date()).toISOString(),
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]

        }).promise();
```

Is it possible to do the same logic with DocumentDB ? I have found [that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.implicit-transactions), it is not possible to do  multi statement transaction in AWS documentDB.

Answer (score 2):

DocumentDB does not support transactions , transactions were introduced to mongoDB in version 4.0 . DocumentDB only supports mongo version 3.6.

Atals in the mongo version in the cloud , https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas.

that supports the newer versions of mongo that do have transactions.